# How to connect (not import!) from MySQL to CSV?

Tags: mysql, csv

I wonder if it is possible to establish a permanent, somehow virtual connection from a MySQL database to a csv file? Just like you connect to a text or csv file from MS ACCESS.

My customer has lots of constantly changing remote csv files and I wonder if I should fully import them into MySQL table or (if possible) just connect to them.

I am not talking about if it is reasonable. I know that this could have a massive impact in server load.

The local database engine of MySQL does not help as the csv files are on remote machines. I would have to copy them into the MySQL database folder on my server. Then I could as well import the file right away into MySQL.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. The CSV engine is the only option to connect to a CSV file from mysql as opposed to importing the data into mysql. Linking to constantly changing CVS files or remote servers is not a great idea anyway from a performance point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect MySQL database to a csv file using ODBC Driver.
Please check following:
https://docs.devart.com/odbc/mysql/excel.htm

If you want to update database from csv file, you can use MySQL Workbench to import data from file to tables.